# How to properly customize SwitchPreferenceCompat so that it behaves like Wi-Fi settings preference

Tags: android

I was wondering, how can I properly customize `SwitchPreferenceCompat`, so that it behaves like Wi-Fi settings preference.

[image]

There're 3 requirements to achieve so

1. Able to distinguish click event between non-switch area (Right side), and switch area (Left side)
2. Able to have correct selector behavior. Meaning, when touching on switch itself, non-switch area shouldn't be highlighted. Vice-versa.
3. Have a seperator UI in between switch area, and non-switch area.

So far, I'm only able to achieve requirement 1, by using the following customized code.

[image]

### Able to distinguish click event between non-switch area (Right side), and switch area (Left side)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;
import android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class CustomSwitchPreferenceCompat extends SwitchPreferenceCompat {
    public CustomSwitchPreferenceCompat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreferenceCompat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreferenceCompat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreferenceCompat(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Recursively go through view tree until we find an android.widget.Switch
     * @param view Root view to start searching
     * @return A Switch class or null
     */
    private SwitchCompat findSwitchWidget(View view){
        if (view instanceof  SwitchCompat){
            return (SwitchCompat)view;
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount();i++){
                View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
                    SwitchCompat result = findSwitchWidget(child);
                    if (result!=null) return result;
                }
                if (child instanceof SwitchCompat){
                    return (SwitchCompat)child;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Get a handle on the 2 parts of the switch preference and assign handlers to them
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (PreferenceViewHolder holder){
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);

        final SwitchCompat switchView = findSwitchWidget(holder.itemView);
        if (switchView!=null){
            switchView.setClickable(true);

            switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "Switch area : Being switch " + isChecked);
                }
            });
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "Non-switch area : Being clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I'm not able to figure out, how can I have correct selector behavior, and a separator UI in between?

Any suggestion, or ready-made library I can utilize on?

Answer (score 0):

Add a ViewGroup and define its `id` as `@android:id/widget_frame`. The preference view will search for this id and insert the contents inside it.

Add the code snippet inside your layout:

```html
<LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="vertical" />
```